# fopen error with the file name

Tags: c

What's the error in this code? I am just new in C language.

```
#define FNAME         "c:\\users\\mahmud\\desktop\\CDs\\"
#define READ_BIN      "rb"

static void open_existing_list()
{
char name[11];
FILE *fptr;

printf("\nPlease enter list name: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s", name);

fptr = fopen(FNAME name ".dat", READ_BIN);
}
```

This code is used to read the file name from the user, then open this File.

```
 D:\Mhmud\Mahmud\Programming\C\Videos\VTC - C  Programming\Course_Project\main.c In function `open_existing_list': 
75 D:\Mhmud\Mahmud\Programming\C\Videos\VTC - C  Programming\Course_Project\main.c syntax error before "name" 
 D:\Mhmud\Mahmud\Programming\C\Videos\VTC - C  Programming\Course_Project\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [main.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define FNAME         "c:\\users\\mahmud\\desktop\\CDs\\
                                                        ^
You're missing the ending quotation mark here: ---------+
```

(Edit: it seems it was just a copy-paste typo.)

Add the missing quote and also fix this:

```
fptr = fopen(FNAME name ".dat", READ_BIN);
```

This only works for string literals, since the concatenation occurs at compile time. You want to write something like this:

```
char fname[512];
snprintf(fname, sizeof(fname), "%s%s.dat", FNAME, name);
fptr = fopen(fname, READ_BIN);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't concatenate a string literal (the `FNAME` macro expansion) with a variable.

To concatenate strings involving variables, you need to do more work. Look up the `strcat()` function, or `snprintf()`. The latter is better.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> fptr = fopen(FNAME name ".dat", READ_BIN);
> ```

You can only concatenate **string literals** like that, and `name` isn't a string literal. Use `sprintf` or `strcat` to build up your path.

```
char path[LENGTH];
snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s%s.dat", FNAME, name);
```